# How to make fromJson of Gson create arraylilst of object

Tags: java, android, json, oop, gson

I've json file which has array of `JSONObject`, after reading and converting it into string, I want to create an `ArrayList` of Java objects, here is my code so far:

```
ArrayList<CountryCode> arrayList;
arrayList = new ArrayList<CountryCode>();
try {
        InputStream ims = context.getResources().getAssets().open("json/" + "countryCodes.json");
        reader = new InputStreamReader(ims);
        int size = ims.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        ims.read(buffer);
        ims.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        arrayList = gson.fromJson(json , ArrayList.class);
        Log.i("countrycode", String.valueOf(arrayList.get(0).getCode()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Where CountryCode is model class has fields for name, countrycode, which is a map from JSONObjects(each json object has name and countrycode)

Getting Error:

> ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be
>   cast to com.myhealthathand.hah.objects.CountryCode

Comment: provide more details like json string and CountryCode class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Define Type List Like this :

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CountryCode>>(){}.getType();

arrayList = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
```

Comment: what listType does?

Comment: Its Define the type of ArrrayList you want to convert, in your case its ArrayList<CountryCode>

Answer (score 0):

Refer following code

```
 **List<CountryCode> arrayList;
        
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<CountryCode>>() {}.getType();**

try {
    InputStream ims = context.getResources().getAssets().open("json/" + "countryCodes.json");
    reader = new InputStreamReader(ims);
    int size = ims.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    ims.read(buffer);
    ims.close();
    json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
     
    **arrayList = new Gson().fromJson(json, collectionType);**

    Log.i("countrycode", String.valueOf(arrayList.get(0).getCode()));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `TypeToken` instead of `ArrayList.class`

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = TypeToken.getParameterized(ArrayList.class, CountryCode).getType();   
ArrayList<ArrayObject> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Also this works if gson is above 2.8.0